# How do I upload multiple files using Firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

```
$("#fileButton1, #fileButton2, #fileButton3").on("change", function(event) {
  selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
});

    function uploadFile() {

      var filename = selectedFile.name;
      var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/files_new/' + filename);
      var uploadTask = storageRef.put(selectedFile);

      uploadTask.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot){

        var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        uploader.value = percentage;

      }, function(error) {

      }, function () {
        window.location.href = "uploadThumbnail.html";
      });
    }

<form class="upload-form">
<progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress>
<input value="upload" id="fileButton1" class="choose-file-btn" type="file">
<input value="upload" id="fileButton2" class="choose-file-btn" type="file">
<input value="upload" id="fileButton3" class="choose-file-btn" type="file">
<button type="button" class="submit-btn" onclick="uploadFile()">Continue</button>
</form>
```

The code above uploads only one file even though I select multiple. How can I make it to push all
files that are selected.

Comment: No, you don't `event.target.files[0]` I see only one file.

Comment: What should I add there instead?

Comment: You have to do the same but for each event.target.files in array. You have many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments i understood you want multiple input files and you want to send all at a time

Follow this and play with your requirement by keeping the below code as reference

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var filesList = [],
        paramNames = [],
        elem = $("form");
    file_upload = elem.fileupload({
        formData:{extra:1},
        autoUpload: false,
        fileInput: $("input:file"),
    }).on("fileuploadadd", function(e, data){
        filesList.push(data.files[0]);
        paramNames.push(e.delegatedEvent.target.name);
    });

    $("button").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        file_upload.fileupload('send', {files:filesList, paramName: paramNames});
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/echo/json/" method="POST">
    <input name="file1[]" type="file" multiple />
    <br />  <br />
    
    <input name="file2[]" type="file" multiple />
    <br />  <br />
    
    <input name="file3[]" type="file" multiple />
    <br />  <br />
 
    <button>send by fileupload send api</button>
</form>
```

You can choose multi files in one input file here

Comment: Demo shows single file upload - and single file upload already works.

Comment: you can select multiple files at a time. click on upload then press CTRL and click the files you want

Comment: I want to upload files from multiple fields not just a single field

Comment: OK, my bad. And form bad it doesn't suggest that. But still your answer `Detailed information provided. Please follow that.` looks like automatic answer it could look better.

Comment: @Zydnar i totally miss understood his question.

Comment: `@Zydnari mis understood his ` who's question and who is Miss Understood?

Comment: I dont know how to use your code with firebase it looks very different. I am really new to this @user6250770

Comment: @LexSha So do as I said in comment - just do the same but for all files in event.target.files especially if for this one file your code works. You can use loop, or forEach and than you can think about more efficient method.

Comment: @Zydnar I did that before I used multiple selectors. it doesnt work. only uploads a single file

Comment: So either you didn't took files from all inputs or you didn't selected many files inside single input you use (look at this answer for reference).

Answer (score 0):

You can save all of the selected files to an array before uploading:

```
var selectedFiles = [];

$("#fileButton1, #fileButton2, #fileButton3").on("change", function(event) {
    var id = $(this).prop('id');
    var item = selectedFiles.find(x => x.id === id);
    if (!item) {
        // if the array doesn't contain any file with this id
        // try to push an object which contains id and the file to the array
        selectedFiles.push({
            id: id,
            file: event.target.files[0]
        });
    } else {
        // if the array already contains some file with this id
        // try to update the file 
        item.file = event.target.files[0];
    }
});

function uploadFile() {
    // uploading file one-by-one
    for (var item of selectedFiles) {
        var filename = item.file.name;
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/files_new/' + filename);
        var uploadTask = storageRef.put(item.file);

        uploadTask.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {

            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            uploader.value = percentage;

        }, function(error) {

        }, function() {
            window.location.href = "uploadThumbnail.html";
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'file' of undefined

Comment: @Tâns still not working. Not uploading any files now. Not even one.

Comment: @LexSha Oh, I'm sorry. Can you show me the error message now? Or have you tried to check the `selectedFiles` with `console.log`? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: Its the same error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'file' of undefined

Comment: @LexSha I can only think about *copy-paste* trouble. Just copying all the code from my answer and run it. Or you can click on the link on the right side of the error message to check where it came from.

Comment: from this line:     `item.file = event.target.files[0]; from this line` @Tân

Comment: @LexSha I got it. You can replace the line `if (item === null)` with `if (!item)` and try again. Sorry, my fault!

Comment: There are no errors anymore but nothing happens. No files are being uploaded progress bar not working either. @Tân